# Django MPTT вывод всех товаров из категории родителя

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm, mptt

Подскажите как достать все товары из категории родителя . у меня есть категории

```
[<Category: Мужчин > Одежда>, <Category: Мужчин > Одежда > Рубашки>, <Category: Мужчин > Одежда > Футболки>, <Category: Мужчин > Обувь>, <Category: Мужчин > Обувь > Кроссовки>].
```

Как я могу получить все товары категории Мужчин queryset? и футболки и кроссовки и тд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сначала получи список всех вложенных подкатегорий внутри [<Category: Мужчин>]
до нужного количества вложенностей

например

```
category_man_id = ...  # укажи стартовую верхнюю категорию

sub1 = list(Category.objects.filter(parent = category_man_id))
sub2 = list(Category.objects.filter(parent__in = sub1))
#  можешь в цикле набрать нужное количество вложенностей

products = Product.objects.filter(category__in = sub1+sub2)
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Работает

Comment: и куда это писать? в модели в саму категорию или модели тип товара или вьюхи категории или вьюхи товар? куда? почему нельза подробней ответить ведь есть люди, которые учатся, а не такие умные!
просто так тупо и писать или надо написать функцию если све оформлено классами?